# What causes the error "Looks like you forgot to register the http module Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule"?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, owin, castle-windsor

I got some DI working in webapi2 using castle.windsor and owin. This is the relevant code:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Bla.Startup))]
    namespace Bla
    {
        public class Startup
        {
            public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
            {
                //...  
                var container = new WindsorContainer().Install(new ControllerInstaller());
                var httpDependencyResolver = new WindsorHttpDependencyResolver(container);
                config.DependencyResolver = httpDependencyResolver;
                //...
            }
    }

    public class ControllerInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
    {
        public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
        {
            container.Register(AllTypes.FromThisAssembly()
            .Pick().If(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Controller"))
            .Configure(configurer => configurer.Named(configurer.Implementation.Name))
            .LifestylePerWebRequest());

            //...
        }
    }

    internal class WindsorDependencyScope : IDependencyScope
    {
        private readonly IWindsorContainer _container;
        private readonly IDisposable _scope;

        public WindsorDependencyScope(IWindsorContainer container)
        {
            if (container == null)
            {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
            }

            _container = container;
            _scope = container.BeginScope();
        }

        public object GetService(Type t)
        {
            return _container.Kernel.HasComponent(t)
            ? _container.Resolve(t) : null;
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type t)
        {
            return _container.ResolveAll(t)
            .Cast<object>().ToArray();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _scope.Dispose();
        }
    }

    internal sealed class WindsorHttpDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
    {
        private readonly IWindsorContainer _container;

        public WindsorHttpDependencyResolver(IWindsorContainer container)
        {
            if (container == null)
            {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
            }

            _container = container;
        }

        public object GetService(Type t)
        {
            return _container.Kernel.HasComponent(t)
             ? _container.Resolve(t) : null;
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type t)
        {
            return _container.ResolveAll(t)
            .Cast<object>().ToArray();
        }

        public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
        {
            return new WindsorDependencyScope(_container);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }
```

One great advantage of owin is that it removes the dependency form system.web. This allows the implementation of fairly efficient (in memory?) integration tests aprat from other things. The problem I am facing is that the line:

```
config.DependencyResolver = httpDependencyResolver;
```

introduces a depency on system. so when I try to run a simple test like this:

```
private TestServer _server;

    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void FixtureInit()
    {
        _server = TestServer.Create<Startup>();
    }

    [Test]
    public voidSomeTest()
    {
        using (var server = TestServer.Create<Startup>())
        {
        HttpResponseMessage response = server.HttpClient.GetAsync("/api/bladibla/test").Result;

        // ...
        }
    }
```

I get:

```
{"Looks like you forgot to register the http module Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule\r\nTo fix this add\r\n<add name=\"PerRequestLifestyle\" type=\"Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule, Castle.Windsor\" />\r\nto the <httpModules> section on your web.config.\...
```

Can I register something in the test project's app.config? Any feedback would be very much welcome.

PS:

I tried adding:

```
<system.web>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="PerRequestLifestyle" type="Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule, Castle.Windsor" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="PerRequestLifestyle" type="Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule, Castle.Windsor" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

to the app.config without success.

PPS:

OK, if I change:

```
container.Register(AllTypes.FromThisAssembly()
                .Pick().If(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Controller"))
                .Configure(configurer => configurer.Named(configurer.Implementation.Name))
                .LifestylePerWebRequest());
```

to:

```
container.Register(AllTypes.FromThisAssembly()
                .Pick().If(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Controller"))
                .Configure(configurer => configurer.Named(configurer.Implementation.Name))
                .LifestyleTransient());
```

it works, which makes sense. The big question is, how can I change this dynamically, depending on whether it is in a deploy/proper web environment or test environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> {"Looks like you forgot to register the http module Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule\r\nTo fix this add\r\n\r\nto the  section on your web.config....

But you tried to register :

> PerRequestLifestyle

See the difference? PerWebRequestLifestyle not PerRequestLifeStyle.

Take a look at [Mauricio Scheffer`s HybridLifeStyles](https://github.com/castleprojectcontrib/Castle.Windsor.Lifestyles/tree/master/Castle.Windsor.Lifestyles) which make the setup of the container for testing very very easy.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Have created installers for proper deployment and testing via xml. This approach seems to work fine for me ...

Answer (score 1):

When doing in memory testing using OWIN, I use the following extension method to override the behaviour:

```
private static void OverridePerWebRequestLifestyle(this IWindsorContainer container)
{
    container.Kernel.ComponentModelCreated += model =>
    {
        if (model.LifestyleType == LifestyleType.PerWebRequest)
        {
            model.LifestyleType = LifestyleType.Transient;
        }
    };
}
```